# ExpressionEngine snapshot add-ons?

Tags: add-on, extension, plugin

My client is forever concerned with making big changes in EE. For instance, using Structure to reorder pages, or renaming entire sections of the site.

I'm wondering: Are there any add-ons that can essentially take a snapshot of the current state of the site, then allow you to roll back to that state if you make a destructive or unwieldy change, or just plain break something?

ideally this would be something that works in the EE system and won't require any manual DB backups or anything.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is not. What i would recommend is that you get a test site setup on either the same server as the live site but in a subdomain so for example 'test.mysite.com', (password protect that of course!), or on a server of identical specification as the live one.

Then take a copy of your live site, put it in the test subdomain and test your changes. Once you are happy that your change is ok and hasn't broken anything, you can apply it to the live site.

There are more complex methods which i'll not go into right now, but the above is, in it's simplest terms, what you should be doing :)

Answer (score 2):

Backup pro http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/backup-pro allows you to backup both the DB and your files, as does Safe harbor http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/safe-harbor.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of backup add-ons. Some of them back up both database and files. So what you can do is simply making a backup of files and database before you make some changes and then simply restore from backup if you do something wrong.